# A safe way to catch an error inside completable future with executor service and a correct way to manage executors

Tags: java, scala, error-handling, executorservice, completable-future

I'm having a class with a huge processing load and for that I'm using a blocking queue for each task type.

The queue is processed recursively, as long as something is inside the queue, the next task is taken and sent away to be processed.

As a code sample, it is something like (*note I use Scala*)

```
def executeNextTask(taskTypeId: String, task: SomeObjectType) = {
  if(aTaskIsNotInProceesing(taskTypeId)){
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(task, executorService)
      .thenAccept(executeNextTask(taskTypeId))
  }
}
```

The trouble is that inside `supplyAsync` some errors may occur and, due to executor service, they are swallowed and I can't catch them. Sometimes, the application is unresponsive and my wild guess is that due to the executors that hang around.

Worth to mention that everything is happening inside a Java EE ecosystem.

My question to you is how can I safely catch an error and how can I protect my code to be consistent?

Comment: I would go for wrapping your code in a `scala.util.Try` and returning it as result for your `CompletableFuture`. Once you encounter a `Failure`, you can handle it however you want.

Comment: Tested with an outer Try, does not work as you mentioned

Comment: Are you ever retrieving the result of the `CompletableFuture`? Only then you will get an Exception or a way to access the `Try`...

Comment: I see that there is no need to retrieve the result, I'm using a static call. Or is it? What about using whenComplete. Could this method be a good error catcher?

Comment: To get information about any error occuring you definitely need to retrieve the result. If you do not handle the exception in the `CompletableFuture` it will first be thrown when calling `get`.